# psutil library installation issue on databricks

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, psutil

I am using psutil library on my databricks cluster which was running fine for last couple of weeks. When I started the cluster today, this specific library failed to install. I noticed there was a different version of psutil got updated in the site.

Currently my python script fails with 'No module psutil'

Tried installing previous version of psutil using pip install but still my code fails with the same error.

Is there any alternative to psutil or is there a way to install it in databricks

Comment: depends on which functionality of `psutil` are using. Did installing previous version of `psutil` give any error?

Comment: I am using psutil.pid_exists. I tried installing the previous version using pip install and got the same error. I also tried installing the Python wheel to the dtabricks cluster and it failed with 'platform not supported'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, there are two ways to install a Python package in Azure Databricks cluster, as below.

1. As the two figures below, move to the `Libraries` tab of your cluster and click the `Install New` button to type the package name of you want to install, then wait to install successfully

   [image]

   [image]
2. Open a notebook, type the shell command as below to install a Python package via pip. Note: At here, for installing in the current environment of databricks cluster, not in the system environment of Linux, you must use `/databricks/python/bin/pip`, not only `pip`.

   ```
   %sh
   /databricks/python/bin/pip install psutil
   ```

   [image]

Finally, I run the code below, it works for the two ways above.

```
import psutil
for proc in psutil.process_iter(attrs=['pid', 'name']):
  print(proc.info)

psutil.pid_exists(<a pid number in the printed list above>)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In additional to @Peter response, you can also use "Library utilities" to install Python libraries.

Library utilities allow you to install Python libraries and create an environment scoped to a notebook session. The libraries are available both on the driver and on the executors, so you can reference them in UDFs. This enables:

- Library dependencies of a notebook to be organized within the
  notebook itself.
- Notebook users with different library dependencies
  to share a cluster without interference.

[image]

**Example:** To install "**psutil**" library using library utilities:

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI("psutil")
```

[image]

**Reference: **[Databricks - library utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#library-utilities)

Hope this helps.